# Shifted Series Join to Dataframe with Concat

Tags: python, pandas, series, concatenation, shift

There is a DataFrame `z` with

```
['title','module_number','beginners','finishers']
```

columns. I need to shift `z.beginners` Series as every last `module_number` should have NaN there, and join it to DataFrame as new column `z.shift`.

I've tried to do it with `pd.concat`. My code:

```
def exp2(df):
    
    fx = df.join(df.beginners[1:].rename('shifted').reset_index()).drop('index', axis =1)
    return fx

def exp3(z,lst):
    
    common = list()
    
    for title in lst:

        df = z[z['title'] == title]
        example = exp2(df)
        common.append(example)
        
    return pd.concat(common)

exp3(z, z.title.unique())
```

That works fine only for the first title in `z` and incorrectly for the second one. However, it doesn't work with any other title:

```
        title module_number beginners finishers shift
    0   Uu    1             518       458       434
    1   Uu    2             434       406       NaN
    3   Kk    1             627       563       27
    4   Kk    2             521       427       NaN
    5   Rr    1             158       142       NaN
    6   Rr    2             136       106       NaN
```

Does anyone know an alternative solution or how I can enhance my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done it the way without loop:

```
shifted = z.beginners.where(z.module_number != 1)[1:]
z.join(shifted.rename('shifted').reset_index()).drop('index',axis = 1)
```

Comment: There was also a possibility to use .shift(1) func